# Properties of unit lower triangular (ULT) matrices

Tags: matrices

In class, the professor gave two properties of **unit lower triangular** (ULT) matrices:

1. ULT matrices are invertible, and their inverse is also ULT.
2. The product of two ULT matrices is also ULT.

The professor didn't provide proofs. Hence, I was wondering if I could find the proofs for these properties. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. What is the determinant of a ULT matrix?
2. Just write out the sum-expression for the $(i, j)$th component of the matrix. Show that the $(i,i)$th component is 1, and the upper-triangular parts always have 0s appearing in every term of the sum.